# how to make isoluminant color patches?

Tags: matlab

I want to make 17 isoluminant gray patches, I am starting from RGB(0 0 0)that is black (by adding 15) to RGB(255 255 255)that is white,so I'll have 17 gray patches. I want to make these patches isoluminant.I have photometer and matlab software but I don't know how can I make these patches. Please indicate me.

Comment: I've tried with the size and noticed I don't really understand what you want to do. Could you add more detail to describe what exactly it is you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

If you want 17 paches, you can't go in steps of 15. That would result in 18 patches (you probably didn't count 0) or 16 if you count neither white nor black. I'll just assume you want the full 18.

First, construct your vector of patches:

```
patches = repmat(0:15:255,3,1)'; %'// transpone to get the right format
```

Next, convert that to Luminance/Chrominance:

```
patches = rgb2ntsc(patches);
```

And, lastly, assign some value to the Luminance component of the results:

```
patches(:,1) = mean(patches(:,1)); %// the mean luminance of all points.
patches(:,1) = patches(1,1); %// the luminance of white
patches(:,1) = 1; %// just 1
```

---

You should be aware, though, that different shades of gray only differ in their Luminance. The Chrominance (Hue and Saturation) of gray is 0. This means that all of your patches will have the exact same color. With this in mind, there is an easier way to do it:

```
targetLuminance = 5; %// take any value here
patchesRGB = repmat(targetLuminance,17,3);
patchesYIQ = repmat([targetLuminance 0 0],17,1);
```

Comment: yes there are 18 patches. Would you plz explain more? all of your mentioned comment are matlab command?I am not professional in matlab.

Comment: yes there are 18 patches. Would you plz explain more? all of your mentioned comment are matlab command?I am not professional in matlab.

Comment: Everything with a gray background is Matlab code, yes.

Comment: what is 5and 17 and 3 and 1 in :targetLuminance = 5; %// take any value here
patchesRGB = repmat(targetLuminance,17,3);
patchesYIQ = repmat([targetLuminance 0 0],17,1);

Comment: That's the dimensions of the vector, 17 patches and 3 color bands (red green blue). 5 is an example luminance, you can put whatever luminance you want there.

Comment: many many thanks, and the last question: this sequence is true?    patches = repmat(0:15:255,3,1)'; %'//
patches = rgb2ntsc(patches);                                                  targetLuminance = 5; %// take any value here
patchesRGB = repmat(targetLuminance,17,3);
patchesYIQ = repmat([targetLuminance 0 0],17,1);

Comment: could you please tell me how can i define size of patches?

Comment: Oh, you want them in a picture? That's a little more complicated. I'm on my mobile right now, will come back to you once i get to my computer.